# Making nested calls to "execute" with Python's Fabric library

Tags: python, fabric

Python's Fabric provides the ability to invoke fabric functions outside of the `fab` utility using the `execute` function.  A contextual problem arises when an `execute` function is invoked within another function that was called using execute.  Fabric loses the context of the outer execute when the inner execute is invoked and never recovers it. For example:

```
env.roledefs = {
    'webservers': ['web1','web2'],
    'load_balancer': ['lb1']
}

@roles('webserver')
def deploy_code():
    #ship over tar.gz of code to unpack.
    ...
    execute(remove_webserver_from_load_balancer, sHost=env.host_string)
    ...
    #shutdown webserver, unpack files, and restart web server
    ...
    execute(add_webserver_to_load_balancer, sHost=env.host_string)

@roles('load_balancer')
def remove_webserver_from_load_balancer(sHost=None):
   ssh("remove_host %s" % sHost)

execute(deploy_code)
```

After the first call to `execute`, Fabric completely loses its context and executes all further commands within the `deploy_code` function with `host_string='lb1'` instead of `'web1'`.  **How can I get it to remember it?**

I came up with this hack, but I feel like it could break on future releases:

```
 with settings(**env):
     execute(remove_webserver_from_load_balancer, sHost=env.host_string)
```

This effectively saves all state and restores it after the call, but seems like an unintended use of the function. Is there a better way to tell Fabric that it's in a nested execute and to use a settings stack or an equivalent method to remember state?

Thanks!

Comment: Why do you use `execute()` inside tasks instead of just calling the functions directly?

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian I think the [documentation](http://docs.fabfile.org/en/1.3.3/usage/execution.html#execute) answers your question: `Fabric’s design eschews magical behavior, so simply calling a task function does not take into account decorators such as roles`.

Comment: correct, jcollado, i need the decorator context

Comment: @jcollado: your premise is that @Andrew Patrick Dowds's intention is to always run `remove_webserver..()` using `@roles('load_balancer')` i.e., you think that the code in question is normative (that most probably is true). But the code doesn't behave as he wants therefore my question is to see *the intent* expressed in plain English.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian, intent is to use the \@roles paradigm so that I can make use of Fabric's nice config system. For every webserver I'm deploying code to, I want every load balancer that refers to it (in the 'load_balancer' roledef), to take it out of rotation before the deploy and restore it after.

Answer (score 1):

Your not using fabric right. As you'd just call `fab deploy_code` instead of running the fabfile like it's python. I'd suggest going through the tutorial for a better idea on how to structure your fabfile.

Anyhow though, you can [look here](http://docs.fabfile.org/en/1.4.1/usage/execution.html#intelligently-executing-tasks-with-execute) for how to use `execute()`, and [here](http://docs.fabfile.org/en/1.4.1/api/core/tasks.html#fabric.tasks.execute) for more of the specifics.

You have a typo in that you've dropped the 's' from the webservers role. Which might account for you not having a good host string when you want it on the second task.

But that aside, you can also set roles and hosts in the execute() command itself.